# Javascript History API: Scroll Restoration

Tags: html5-history

Can i get History history.scrollRestoration value? Can not find any info about this.

I need to save scroll value, like browser do by default. But my page has overflow:hidden on start, and i need to scroll manualy, to save postion if user goes back.